# When is a Java subroutine not a method?

Tags: java, methods, subroutine

I came across this during learning Java in the beginning, but I am learning top down, so I would like some direction:

This was on a [Java tutorial](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c2/s3.html#basics.3.1) relatively early on:

> As one final general note, you should be aware that subroutines in Java are often referred to as methods. Generally, the term "method" means a subroutine that is contained in a class or in an object. Since this is true of every subroutine in Java, every subroutine in Java is a method (with one very technical exception). The same is not true for other programming languages. Nevertheless, the term "method" is mostly used in the context of object-oriented programming, and until we start doing real object-oriented programming in Chapter 5, I will prefer to use the more general term, "subroutine." However, I should note that some people prefer to use the term "method" from the beginning.

My question is what is that "one very technical exception."  Since I am learning multiple stack technologies, I would like to know this specific exception he is referring to.   It comes from this tutorial :
http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c2/

Comment: Can the question title be edited to something more useful. Like "What Java subroutines are not methods?" as I believe that is the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [chapter 5](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c5/s2.html) of the tutorial you linked to:

> Constructors are subroutines, but they are subroutines of a special
>   type. They are certainly not instance methods, since they don't belong
>   to objects. Since they are responsible for creating objects, they
>   exist before any objects have been created. They are more like static
>   member subroutines, but they are not and cannot be declared to be
>   static. In fact, according to the Java language specification, they
>   are technically not members of the class at all! In particular,
>   constructors are **not** referred to as "methods."

Comment: Funnily enough constructors appear as instance methods in bytecode. (The object allocation is separated out into the code using `new`, this allows the same code to be called by constructors of derived classes.)

Answer (score 2):

Class [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) are not methods.